# Convert vector<vector<int>> to QVector<int> or QVector2D<int> or something

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qvector

I use QDataStream to write the variable to .dat file, so the variable I'm writing should be in the form of QVector or QVector2D

```
vector<vector<int>> vec;
// save
QFile file("save.dat");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QDataStream out(&file);
out << QVector2D<int>::fromStdVector(vec);

// load
QFile file("save.dat");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QDataStream in(&file);
QVector2D<int> qqi;
in >> qqi; vec = qqi.toStdVector();
```

Error: QVector2D is not a template: out << ...

Comment: `QVector2D` is not a template and stores float values.

Comment: you should prob. be using [`QDataStream &QDataStream::writeBytes(const char *s, uint len)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#writeBytes) and [`QDataStream &QDataStream::readBytes(char *&s, uint &l)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#readBytes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use Qt types to write into the datastream. Just serialize the data in `vec`. For that to work you also need to store the sizes of the structures.

```
int
main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;
  vec.resize( 2 );
  vec[0] = { 1, 2 };
  vec[1] = { 3, 4, 5 };
  // save
  {
    QFile file( "save.dat" );
    file.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly );
    QDataStream out( &file );
    out << vec.size();
    for( auto& inner : vec ) {
      out << inner.size();
      out.writeBytes(
          reinterpret_cast<const char*>( inner.data() ),
          inner.size() * sizeof( int ) );
    }
  }
  vec.clear();
  {
    // load
    QFile file( "save.dat" );
    file.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly );
    QDataStream in( &file );
    size_t num;
    in >> num;
    vec.resize( num );
    for( auto& inner : vec ) {
      in >> num;
      inner.resize( num );
      auto buffer = reinterpret_cast<char*>( inner.data() );
      uint bytes = num * sizeof( int );
      in.readBytes( buffer, bytes );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Thomas said, `QVector2D` is not a template. So `QVector2D<int>` is meaningless. You mean just `QVector2D`, although that's a 2-vector of `float`s.

Your question isn't clear to me, in that I'm not sure if you want to use the `QDataStream` or if it's just a way you figured out. Because if you don't need to save it, the answer is just

```
QVector<QVector2D> toQtTypes(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& v) {
    QVector<QVector2D> result;
    for (const auto& point : v) {
        Q_ASSERT(point.size() == 2);
        if (point.size() == 2) {
            result.push_back(QVector2D(point[0], point[1]));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```